# How to close subprocess popen

Tags: python, subprocess, python-imaging-library

I tried

```
viewer = subprocess.Popen(["explorer", "filename"])
```

which opened the image but to close this I tried

```
viewer.terminate()
```

**which works fine but if I use any while loop or sleep between these lines this will not going to terminate the explorer**.

Also tried

```
viewer.kill()
```

If it can be done with other library, it will be fine.

Comment: Where was the call to `show()` please?

Comment: Actually i used img.Show() since it is not possible to close i use subprocess and psutils method

Comment: Please try to improve your question... clearer questions tend to get better answers. Your title says you use **PIL** `Image.show()`, but your code starts `explorer` and your wording says you use `Photos`.